# how to insert a new value in between two values in mysql .?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySql database that contains a table have which four fields Id(primary key & auto increment), Node, Distance,pressure.

```
ID      Node    Distance    Pressure 
001     15       320        45
002     16       420        41
003     17       520        45
.
.
.
.
10000    256     1245        1542
```

The problem is that, if you want to insert a new record then the New record's ID become 10001
but I want to insert a New Record Between two records. for ex: i need to insert a new record between 001 and 002 here is the problem. I need the New record's ID as 002.
currently I am solving this problem by updating tables .But it is not feasible for large number of records.

Comment: It seems that `ID` is not a real primary key then :)

Comment: Due to the fact that the `id` column is set to auto_increment, there's no other way than what you're doing (updating rows with id > 2 in your example, then inserting the new row with id(2)).

Comment: Could you give some more background? Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can Insert a Row if ID is an `auto-increment` equivalent to **[Identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx)**, Considering `SQL Server`

**Update:** 
Also in `Mysql`

**[Auto-Increment in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)** we can't insert Row if ID is and `auto-increment`.

Thanks [Mahmoud Gamal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722783/mahmoud-gamal)

Comment: New **Users** often make **`mistakes`** in **`Tagging`** **:)**

Comment: Then how do i solve this problem .?How can i represent the ID ?

Comment: I am Using Mysql database . that's why tagged mysql

Comment: @user1938284 Ok, can you please tell me what would be new **ID** that you are going to **Insert** into Table between **ID** `001` and `002`

Comment: @inhan i Didnt get you. your saying that i need to update the whole table right.? could you please tell me how to do it.?

Comment: You're still right, this is also valid for MySQL, but update the link to [`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) instead of `IDENTITY` in SQL Server.

Comment: @jack its for water authority.

Comment: @user1938284 - There are two issues, first: you can't insert a row between two rows, because rows are not stored with a specific order, you can't till that the row 001 and 002 are stored after each other. The second is that the table identity, must still the same and not for update, if this is really a primary key. Other wise change this and make another column a primary key instead and then you can change this column the way you want.

Comment: @Luv the ID is currently as auto increment. so the new id will be 10001 coz we have total 10000 records. but i need to insert it in between 001 and 002 .

Comment: @user1938284 Do u want that when you **`Select`** the **table_columns**, then the **ID 10001** should be displayed between **001** and **002** ?

Comment: @Luv Yea, but.. then ID 10001 should change to 002 and 002 to 003 and 003 to 004 and so on..

Comment: @user1938284: In **simple** words it's not **Possible** in the way you want. You have **Update** rows as you were doing before. :)

Comment: @user1938284 - This column that you need to change, is declared as `Primary key` and `auto_incremental` so you can't change it. Furthermore this is an identity number, it means it shouldn't be changed, how do you know what this row is if you change its identity? like your ID Number. So, I think you need to change your table structure a little bit, so that you change this column and rename it, and have a new column to be an identity and primary key and don't consider updating this column ever.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Don't use auto_increment.
A better answer however is to question why you would want to do this!